# Value mapping by condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, mapping

I have a raw data frame that looks like this:

```
test
   id class                time
1   1 start 2019-06-20 00:00:00
2   1   end 2019-06-20 00:05:00
3   1 start 2019-06-20 00:10:00
4   1   end 2019-06-20 00:15:00
5   2   end 2019-06-20 00:20:00
6   2 start 2019-06-20 00:25:00
7   2   end 2019-06-20 00:30:00
8   2 start 2019-06-20 00:35:00
9   3   end 2019-06-20 00:40:00
10  3 start 2019-06-20 00:45:00
11  3   end 2019-06-20 00:50:00
12  3 start 2019-06-20 00:55:00
```

My goal is to map the values to an output table for each id *only* where there is a `start` and an `end` in consecutive order (time).  Therefore, the output would look like:

```
output
  id               start                 end
1  1 2019-06-20 00:00:00 2019-06-20 00:05:00
2  1 2019-06-20 00:10:00 2019-06-20 00:15:00
3  2 2019-06-20 00:25:00 2019-06-20 00:30:00
4  3 2019-06-20 00:45:00 2019-06-20 00:50:00
```

I have tried with the `dplyr` package, but

```
test %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(time) %>% starts_with("start")
Error in starts_with(., "start") : is_string(match) is not TRUE
```

`starts_with` always throws an error.  I would like to avoid writing a for loop because I am sure this can be handled by a few chain operations.  Any ideas for a workaround in `dplyr` or `data.table`?

Comment: Try `test %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(time) %>% filter(class %>% starts_with("start"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
test[, {
        si <- which(class=="start" & shift(class, -1L)=="end")
        .(id, start=time[si], end=time[si + 1L])
    }, by=.(id)]
```

output:

```
   id                 start                 end
1:  1 1 2019-06-20 00:00:00 2019-06-20 00:05:00
2:  1 1 2019-06-20 00:10:00 2019-06-20 00:15:00
3:  2 2 2019-06-20 00:25:00 2019-06-20 00:30:00
4:  3 3 2019-06-20 00:45:00 2019-06-20 00:50:00
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
test <- fread("id,class,time
1,start,2019-06-20 00:00:00
1,end,2019-06-20 00:05:00
1,start,2019-06-20 00:10:00
1,end,2019-06-20 00:15:00
2,end,2019-06-20 00:20:00
2,start,2019-06-20 00:25:00
2,end,2019-06-20 00:30:00
2,start,2019-06-20 00:35:00
3,end,2019-06-20 00:40:00
3,start,2019-06-20 00:45:00
3,end,2019-06-20 00:50:00
3,start,2019-06-20 00:55:00")
```

Comment: when I try this on your dataset or mine, I get `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘shift’ for signature ‘"character"’`

Comment: i am using `data.table_1.12.2`

Comment: oh then there is a clash in the naming of functions between packages

Answer (score 3):

I usually use cumsum() is these cases

```
test %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(time, .by_group = TRUE) %>%   # should use .by_group arg
  mutate(flag = cumsum(class == "start")) %>%
  group_by(id, flag) %>%
  filter(n() == 2L) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(class, time) %>%
  select(-flag)
```

Comment: Nice answer. The result has the end/start columns in the wrong order. Maybe using factor (as in my answer) works? I'm not familiar with spread() so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, we can first `filter` the rows which follow the `"start"` and `"end"` pattern, create groups of 2 rows and `spread` to long format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

test %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(class == "start" & lead(class) == "end" | 
         class == "end" & lag(class) == "start") %>%
  group_by(group = gl(n()/2, 2)) %>%
  spread(class, time) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group) %>%
  select(id, start, end)

#     id  start              end               
#   <int> <dttm>              <dttm>             
#1     1 2019-06-20 00:00:00 2019-06-20 00:05:00
#2     1 2019-06-20 00:10:00 2019-06-20 00:15:00
#3     2 2019-06-20 00:25:00 2019-06-20 00:30:00
#4     3 2019-06-20 00:45:00 2019-06-20 00:50:00
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This throws the following error: `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"tbl_df"’`

Comment: @the_darkside yes, I think there is another naming clash. Try using `dplyr::select` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can keep each `start` row plus the `end` immediately after it (if any), then use `dcast` to switch from long to wide form:

```
test[, 
  if (.N >= 2) head(.SD, 2)
, by=.(g = rleid(id, cumsum(class=="start"))), .SDcols=names(test)][, 
  dcast(.SD, id + g ~ factor(class, levels=c("start", "end")), value.var="time")
]

   id g               start                 end
1:  1 1 2019-06-20 00:00:00 2019-06-20 00:05:00
2:  1 2 2019-06-20 00:10:00 2019-06-20 00:15:00
3:  2 4 2019-06-20 00:25:00 2019-06-20 00:30:00
4:  3 7 2019-06-20 00:45:00 2019-06-20 00:50:00
```

`rleid` and `cumsum` are used to find the sequences; and `factor` is needed to tell `dcast` the column order.

*Side note*: This is essentially the same as @cheetahfly's answer (I didn't realize when I posted): since the cumsum is increasing, it is sufficient to group by id + cumsum and there's no need to use rleid (which is for tracking runs of values). The only difference is that my approach woudl keep a run like start, end, end; while the other answer would filter it out with the n() == 2 check.